# Add js scripts in the application.html.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails, I know that we add our `css` and `js` files in `application.html.erb` file.

But do we also add the js scripts in the same file?

For example this script below

```
   <script>
    $(function () {
      $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
        auto: true,
        speed: 500,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        pager: true,
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: did you add and check? what is the issue?

Comment: didn't add and check...

Comment: why you need to add them , you just need to add them in there respective js file

Comment: @SurajShukla Can you please tell me how did you call that function in erb file?

Answer (score 2):

You can add any scripts in ***application.html.erb***, but i think will be better to require ***application.js*** in ***application.html.erb*** with javascript_include_tag:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

and include any scripts from javascript folder in application.js

```
//= require library_name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom js file in `/assets/javascripts` folder and write all your js code and it will load in your page also.